# How to redistribute shards to all of the available nodes for a single Elasticsearch index

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sharding

I have an `Elasticsearch` cluster on `AWS`. It is of `66Tb` size. There is an index there that is of size `1.4Tb` and it has `21 shards` with `70gb` size each. The cluster has `20` data nodes but the shards are living only on `10` data nodes. I want to distribute shards evenly across the available nodes, how to do that?

Comment: Do you have any [shard allocation awareness/filtering rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness) set up in your cluster? If yes, can you provide them?

Comment: I didn't set up the initial cluster, so I am not sure. Is there any command to find it out?

Comment: What do you get when running this `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults&filter_path=*.cluster.routing.allocation*` ?

Comment: There are `3` sections: `persistent`, `transient`, and `defaults`. In `transient` I see `awareness` key which is an empty object. There are no other `awareness` keys anywhere. Which keys are you interested in? I could add the output of the whole command to the question if needed.

Comment: Feel free to update your question with the response you get.

Comment: Ok, just added it, please see